# Magento2 : Using RequireJS module conditional of whether it exists

Tags: magento2.3, requirejs, tinymce

It is possible to use RequireJS to inject some modules into a custom script, for example:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'tinymce',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($, modal, tinymce) {
    "use strict";
    ...
});
```

However, it looks like in Magento 2.3 the module `tinymce` is no longer supported, but it is possible to use `tinymce4`. However, that is not backwards-compatible.

The question is, is it possible to check whether a module exists before defining it? It have tried with `require.defined` and `require.specified` but they appear to check against what's defined with `define()`, not what exists.

Ideally I'd want something like this:

```
var tinymce_module = requirejs.moduleExists('tinymce4') ? 'tinymce4' : 'tinymce';
define([
    'jquery',
    tinymce_module,
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($, modal, tinymce) {
    "use strict";
    ...
});
```

P.S. Any help regarding loading TinyMCE across Magento 2 versions specifically would be appreciated in the comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's available to require ext js into define.

You have a js file named `abc.js` stored at `/Nspace/Module/view/frontend/web/js/abc.js`

Solution 1 Using `Nspace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

First Step: create `Nspace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
map: {
        '*': {
            'abc': 'Nspace_Module::js/abc',
         }
}
```

If your js file required `jquery` using shim option for depending `jquery`.

```
var config = {    
    map: {
            '*': {
                'abc': 'Nspace_Module::js/abc',
             }
    },
    shim: {
        'abc': {
            deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
```

where you want to require `abc js` include `'abc'` to your required list.

```
define([
   'abc',
], function(abc) {
    "use strict";
    ...
});
```

More info please read here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html

**good look!.**

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand from your answer how to require different JS files based on a condition that I set. The condition is not a dependency, it's arbitrary, e.g. a configuration, or a Magento version, or anything else.